# Applying a map elementwise to every element on a Series (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

When I try the following:

```
# Define the mapping
def my_float_to_string(f):
  return "{:g}".format(f)

# This returns numpy.float64
type(my_xls['Subject'][0])

my_df['foo'] = my_df['foo'].map(float_to_string)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Unkonwn format code 'g'for object of type 'str'
```

However, the following works well

```
test = my_float_to_string(5.0)
print test 
'5'
```

Why am I unable to apply my function elementwise on my  `Series` object?

Also, why do DataFrames and Series have different method names for elementwise operations (i.e. `map`  for Series vs `applymap` for DataFrames)

Comment: Because they're strings not floats... To format a number as a float it has to be a float (or at the least - numeric)

Comment: Thanks Jon@, but I am confused, `my_df['foo']` holds float values (see my updated OP).

Comment: Change your function to include a first line of `print f, type(f)`... see what you get...

Answer (score 1):

When using

```
my_df['foo'] = my_df['foo'].map(float_to_string)
```

`float_to_string` receive a string and not a float. To check that you can add an

```
assert(isinstance(f, float))
```

in `float_to_string`.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, it turns out that I had a couple of nan values in my dataframe (everything else was float64, so I could not see it)

Comment: Inclusion of NaN shouldn't be a problem in the DataFrame column of `float`s. For example, `"{:g}".format(np.NaN)` works just fine and prints "nan".

Comment: Check out the `na_action` argument to `Series.map`